# npm run build giving error with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Running npm build creates the error:

Failed to compile.

./src/index.css
    BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
        at Array.forEach ()

After viewing other guides online on updating several packages etc, running npm install, this still doesn't work. I want to know a general practise to stop this from happening in the future and to also fix this current issue.

What I would also like to know - is can the app be ran on a server still even with the build failing, as currently i have this app deployed and it actually runs, but its running an old version of the code and seemingly on the server i can run npm build and it works although it doesnt display any of the new code, actually i cant stop the process.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@shopify/polaris": "latest",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "latest",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid these errors would be amazing, or general advice on how react apps are deployed, as I said it seems to be deployed even though the build doesnt work locally.

Comment: I suppose you are using create-react-app ?

Comment: Can you `ls -al`?

Comment: Maybe you have configured your IDE to hides files that are in `.gitignore`? Try `npm install -g serve && serve -s build` and see if it works.

Comment: I am slightly confused, I know that react-scripts introduced browserlist support, but I think they did it in v2.x, but you are using v1.x. Also, I do not see any entry in `package.json` for browserlist. Can you try running npm install again, if it fails again, try npm install after deleting the `node_modules`, I fear that your node_modules has some mixed stuff in it

Comment: I've tried that (installing) many times, cant i just update react scripts then?